# How to add a custom filtering field to SearchPanes

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to display fields in DataTables SearchPanes that doesn't exist in the table.

E.g. I have following table:

```
|  Foos |  Bars |
---------------
|  foo1 |  bar1 |
```

And I defined SearchPanes for just `Foos`.

In the Foos pane I can see `foo1` because this is what exists in the table.
But I would like also to show `foo2` there, so when user clicks on `foo2` it will result in empty table (because this value doesn't exist).

Is that possible with SearchPanes?

Comment: The only way I know to do this is using [`columns.searchPanes.options`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.searchPanes.options). This lets you define custom entries in a search pane (exactly what you want!), but the problem is: As soon as you have defined one such option, it replaces all the "default" entries in the pane (not at all what you want!). I suppose you could maybe pre-build that section for every unique value in the column - and then add your custom entry. Seems like a lot of trouble for a value which will anyway have a "0" displayed next to it in the pane.

Comment: @andrewjames I tried that but it has one major issue - it doesn't allow you to define options that have no matches in the table. Or more precisely it doesn't filter the table if you define such option (it will show all entries in table and in the pane it will say that there are no matches) :(. I think I would need to create a bogus entry in the table to make it work.

Comment: I did not have that issue: I simply hard-coded the function for that entry to always return `false`. (A bogus entry would be much simpler, I agree).

Comment: I did exactly the same, function with return false. When I changed to true the option showed.

Comment: That is curious. We must be doing something different, somewhere - or I have misunderstood the question, always a possibility. https://jsfiddle.net/906c8auo/

Comment: Ha, I have cascadePanes enabled, when I disable it it works :)